# addActor is not a function

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm developing an extension to the gnome shell. My extension requires a slider bar to a indicator on the status area. I had some problems setting it, I was writing my code on this [slightly outdated reference](http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/gnome-shell-javascript-source.html#popupMenu), the main problem was that the 'PopupSliderMenuItem' was missing in the source code. So i did some research and found out that it was deleted. This [commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/commit/js/ui?id=73cd595b73a31d84259eb488deb6075d35e8b4d2) has more information.

So I tried to follow this (updated) code on the commit:

```
this._slider = new Slider.Slider(0);
this._slider.connect('value-changed', Lang.bind(this, this._sliderChanged));
this._slider.connect('drag-end', Lang.bind(this, this._notifyVolumeChange));

this.item = new PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem({ activate: false });
this.item.addActor(this._slider.actor, { expand: true });
```

I refactored this code to my project, and it looks like this:

```
this.slider = new Slider.Slider(0.5);
this.slider.connect('value-changed', Lang.bind(this, this._sliderChanged));
this.slider.connect('drag-end', Lang.bind(this, this._setNewColorTemperature));

this.sliderContainer = new PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem();
this.sliderContainer.addActor(this.slider.actor, { expand: true });
this.menu.addMenuItem(this.sliderContainer);
```

The first block is on the gnome-shell source code (it sets the volume slider). My code (the second block) is throwing this exception on the 'addActor' line:

```
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: Extension ****censored**** had error: TypeError: sliderContainer.addActor is not a function
```

Anyone has any idea why this error is happening? The strangest thing is that the source code for the [PopupBaseMenuItem class](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/popupMenu.js) has the function that I'm calling.

If you need any other information I'm happy to provide.

Comment: Can you generate a simple fully contained example

Comment: from what I can tell, PopupBaseMenuItem calls addActor through "grabHelper"  [Line 1191](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/popupMenu.js#n1191) this._grabHelper.addActor(source);

Comment: The grabHelper is for the PopupMenuManager class, I was needing something for the PopupBaseMenuItem. But nevermind, I found the solution after getting some sleep hehe, I'll post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking with more attention to the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/popupMenu.js#n70), I found that the right way to set an actor is through the .actor property.

So my code is looking like this now (and it's working):

```
this.slider = new Slider.Slider(0.5);
this.slider.connect('value-changed', Lang.bind(this, this._sliderChanged));
this.slider.connect('drag-end', Lang.bind(this, this._setNewColorTemperature));

this.sliderContainer = new PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem();
this.sliderContainer.actor = this.slider.actor;
this.menu.addMenuItem(this.sliderContainer);
```